# Responsive date from date to css layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wonder what is best approach to obtain date from date to layot.
So it should be something like:

```
float center for below two lines
<label for date from><input datepicker> <label for date to><input datepicker>//line 1
<button>//line 2
```

I've build already(with blessing of bootstrap):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
       <div class="float-right">
           <span>date from</span>
           <input>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
       <div class="float-left">
           <span>date to</span>
           <input>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and that almost fits my needs, beside that on mobiles floats destroy whole layout. I think that those float divs should have some how dynamic float depends on resolution or better solution to make on small resolution width 100% for both span and input to create moblie layout like:

```
label from
input
label to
input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found nice solution using botstrap css

```
<form class="form-inline text-center">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
       <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If You already have  this one. If you have any question regarding this. ask me in comment. If I have Make any mistake. Please comment below I will try my best to solve your problem. Good luck.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.pickyDate').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });
    });
```

```css
.right{float:right !important;}
 .col-sm-12{width:50% !important;}
 @media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .col-sm-12{width:100% !important;}
 .right{float:none !important;}
 input.pickyDate{width:100%;}
  /*Usefull class*/
  .topMar {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="right">
      <span class="lable">date from</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="click to show datepicker" class="pickyDate" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 topMar">
    
      <span class="lable">date to</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="click to show datepicker" class="pickyDate" />
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Almost. On large screen labels should not create new line.

Comment: on large - all components in one line.
on mobile - each component as new line(that already works fine)

Comment: Ok you will get updated code soon. I will let you know

Comment: Thx for try but still no. I mean it takes now 1 line, but look on it on full screen. Inputs of date have like width 500px it looks really bad. Thats why I was fighint with floating it to center. Becase datepicker on large resolution should be small and centered. You can for example change first line of styles from width 85% to 25% and then u saw there is need to add floating to center input on large screens

Comment: @user2771738 problem col-sm-12 width 100% below screen 992px. So No you can check it. Maybe This will be the answer you are looking for. 
CODE UPDATED

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you shouldn't need to use floats at all. Bootstrap will automatically take care of the alignment of your `<div>`s. Just reverse the order of your two input fields; the first one will be on the left.